# php code to increment month inside for loop

Tags: php, pdo

i have starting date ..

i need to add months in starting date inside for loop

for ex -
startingdate = 25-03-2015

and  my loop runs two time then it generate like below

25-04-2015

25-05-2015

thats it...

```
$startingdate = $_POST['startingdate']; 
$dates = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate . " +" . " 1MONTHS -1 DAYS"));
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++)
        {                       
        $coupondate = $dates;   
}
```

Comment: Use explode function ? Get index 0 and last , make your loop, where is the problem  ?

Comment: You can use `MAX` and `MIN` in sql and `max()` and `min()` in PHP to determine the highest and lowest values. Depending on how you go about doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your results are returned with commas separting. Then use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to return an array of values. Then using [max()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) and [min()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) in php you can set your lower and upper limits to loop through.

But if you're getting all the results anyway, [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) should do the trick, then just loop through them.

```
$result = "100,101,102,103";
$arr = explode(",", $result);

foreach ($arr as $number) {
    echo $number;
}
```

Or with min / max:

```
$result = "100,101,102,103";
$arr = explode(",", $result);

$min = min($arr);
$max = max($arr);

for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
   echo $i;
}
```

Comment: for EX - $startingdate = 25-03-2015 
$dates = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate . " +" . " 1MONTHS")); $coupondate = $dates;  then it generate  25-04-2015,25-05-2015 it increment upto loop runs..

Comment: Suggest you look on stack overflow, as this question has likely been answered before. Or post another question, as it's not related to this one. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at 
[min()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) and 
[max()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)

```
$points=array(500,501,502,503,504,505,506);

$min=min($points);

$max=max($points);

for($i=$min;$i<$max+1;++$i{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: can you suggest how to increment date to +1months in every loop runs...      for EX - $startingdate = 25-03-2015 $dates = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate . " +" . " 1MONTHS")); $coupondate = $dates; then it generate 25-04-2015,25-05-2015 it increment upto loop runs.. plz

Answer (score 0):

If your data is stored lower to upper :

```
$text = '500,501,502,503,504,505,506';

$explode = explode(',',$text);
$index = count($explode)-1;


for ($i=$explode[0]; $i<=$explode[$index]; $i++)
{       
    echo $i;
}
```

If order can change, add  :

```
sort($explode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
//after connected with a database

$data = (explode(",", $rows["points"]));

for ($i=min($data); $i<=max($data); $i++)
{       

}
```

## Note : If the separation between words is ', ' (a comma and space) then change with this :

```
$data = (explode(", ", $rows["points"]));
```